# Pytorch: Missing key(s) in state_dict

Tags: pytorch

I tried converting a pytorch model into deployment (ios) so I'm converting a model to either cafffe or Onnx (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/typeerror-forward-missing-2-required-positional-arguments-cap-lens-and-hidden/20010/8). My initial error was only having 'one layer" inside an lstm yet I encountered another problem.

I tried implementing two layers (nlayers=2) by instantiating a new rnn object called text_encoder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3rtB.png)

Yet I'm given an error of some key(s) inside the state_dict is missing. This error doesn't occur for having one layer yet but I do get an error during the conversion (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/typeerror-forward-missing-2-required-positional-arguments-cap-lens-and-hidden/20010/8)

I'm not sure if this is happening because the model I loaded only had one layer or another problem. How can I recover missing key's while adding a new layer? Or is that impossible? Original post (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/missing-key-s-in-state-dict/20154) and (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/typeerror-forward-missing-2-required-positional-arguments-cap-lens-and-hidden/20010/11)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrgcV.png)

Comment: I have a similar problem (thought it was the same, but realized you have missing keys, whereas I have keys without values): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605747/errors-converting-pytorch-unet-tiramisu-into-coreml-via-onnx